How to log output message from a Stored Procedure using SQLAlchemy
I am trying to run a Stored Procedure in my SQL Database using SQLAlchemy and python.
My connection function returns the sqlalchemy engine something like this -->
`
import logging
from sqlalchemy import Connection, text
import sqlalchemy as sa
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('my class')

def get_sql_connection() -> Connection:

    server_name = ''
    database_name = ''
    logger.info(f"Creating SQL ALchemy connection to {database_name} on {server_name}")
    try:
        conn_string = f'mssql+pyodbc://@{server_name}/{database_name}?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
        engine = sa.create_engine(conn_string, fast_executemany=True, echo=True)
        
        logger.info("SQL ALchemy connection created")
        
        return engine
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(
            f"Failed to create SQL Alchemy connection {e.__class__.__name__}:{e}"
        )
`

Then I am using this engine to build a connection in another python class that will run a Stored Procedure.
`


class my_class_name:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.engine = get_sql_connection()
        self.connection = get_sql_connection().connect()
        self.cursor = get_sql_connection().raw_connection().cursor()
        self.logger = logger

    def run_stored_proc(self) -> None:
        results = self.connection.execute(text("""EXEC MY_STORED_PROC @printCmds=1"""))
        for message in results:
            self.logger.info(message)

`

This gives me an error -
sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1338, in _we_dont_return_rows
    raise exc.ResourceClosedError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

I tried another options like to print the result and it shows
<sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult object at 0x00000453452342>

The sql connection and the code is able to execute the stored procedure but not able to log any messages that are generated from it.
I found a way to be done using pyodbc but my project requirements want us to use SQLAlchemy only.
pyodbc has this option which can help logging all the output messages from the Stored Procedure execution --
while self.cursor.nextset():
     self.logger.info(self.cursor.messages[0][-1][54:])

Is there any similar way to achieve using SQLAlchemy?
How do I log these messages using SQLAlchemy?
